# Excel Refresh from Dynamics 365

Tags: excel, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I am trying to get this add-in in Excel - Refresh from Dynamics 365.

[image]

I have added the add-in and also installed Dynamics in Office 365 but still cannot see the add-in.

Answer (score 0):

I am hoping you got this fixed but if not, ensure you have the latest version of Excel installed it appears via your screenshot that the Microsoft Dynamics 365 Add-in is already installed.

Try pulling data from a page/form/table in Dynamics - (MS Office icon > OPEN in Excel). Note clicking Export into Excel will only allow you to manipulate data locally - it will not allow you to publish data back to D365.